# What is the "socket" on Hirose DF13-series jumpers?

Tags: identification, jumper

For this pre-crimped wire family with a "socket" at one or both ends:

```
Hirose H*B**-101**-**
```

[image: hirose ordering code]

with these mechanical drawings:

[image: front]

[image: top]

[image: side]

All units expressed in mm. Here is an [example device](https://www.digikey.ca/product-detail/en/hirose-electric-co-ltd/H4BXT-10102-B8/H4BXT-10102-B8-ND/425871). What is the socket standard? Is this quick connect? If so, what is the accepted tab size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would buy this part and insert the socket into a socket housing, rather than buying the wire and crimp terminal separately and crimping the terminal onto the wire yourself. This would save you the cost of buying a fairly pricey crimping tool (even the manual tool runs close to $700), and ensure you get good quality crimps with good pull strength.

The socket housing is sold under part number DF13-xS-1.25C (single-row) or DF13-xxD-1.25C (dual-row). An example of the single-row socket with wires inserted is shown in the DF13 [catalog](https://www.hirose.com/product/en/download_file/key_name/DF13/category/Catalog/doc_file_id/31687/?file_category_id=4&item_id=38&is_series=1):

[image]

Comment: OK; that gets me closer; what is the male counterpart? Regular old rectangular pin header?

Comment: @Reinderien, can't you use Digi-key search engines? This is not "close", this is exactly what you are looking for. The mating part(s) are usually shown at the bottom of the item.

Comment: @Reinderien, check the catalog I linked to. It gives you the PNs for all the available sizes of wire-side housings, headers, contacts, etc. The contact pitch is 1.25 mm, so I wouldn't call that a "regular pin header". For this fine pitch, I'd definitely recommend to stick to using the correct mating part and not try to connect to a Molex/TE/other part that superficially looks similar.

Answer (score 1):

The part where this pictured thing goes to is called "housing", see, for example, Digi-Key search for "[Hirose DF13](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/connectors-interconnects/rectangular-connectors-housings/319?k=Hirose%20DF13)"

All information is already in the link you provided. The bottom shows an example of 3-pin "socket housing". Clicking on the provided image leads you to the housing itself, and the bottom gives you a list of mating products.

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to the contact that would be a part such as [DF13-2630SCF](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/hirose-electric-co-ltd/DF13-2630SCF/H9992CT-ND/241817) with is used on the DF13 series of jumper wires 26-30AWG

[image]

If it is the housing you are looking for here is a list of the DF13 housings it will work with.
https://www.digikey.com/products/en?PPV=1811|4|241817

Comment: Yes and no. I was wondering if this is an implementation of a more generic standard, and the answer seems to be no; it looks proprietary.

Comment: Yes this is proprietary.

Comment: If you want generic you are probably best to go with a quick connect or "faston" which is a TE brand

Comment: Probably. Unfortunately, I wasn't able to find leads pre-crimped with quick-connect.